# How to display images wrapped inside url() in Django

Tags: html, css, django, static

Here is the following code in an html file:

```
<div class="hero-wrap js-fullheight" style="background-image: url('images/bg_1.jpg');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
```

I'm new to web development and am trying to figure out where I need to put the {% static ' ' %} command to display images/any style when they are referred through url(). I added the {% load static %} at the top already.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`{% static … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static) will be replaced with the url, so you can render this with:

```
<div style="background-image: url('{% static 'path/to/image.jpeg' %}');">
```